# Why don't my http requests appear in the firebase performance monitor console?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-performance

I added Firebase 4.2.0 and  Firebase Performance Monitor to my iOS application. I wanted to see what information I can get for my HTTP/S requests, but unfortunately my requests do not appear in the Network Requests tab. All I can see are: 
"cloudconfig.googleapis.com/**", "app-measurement.com/**", "jmt17.google.com/**", "device-provisioning.googleapis.com/**" and "www.googleapis.com/**" which seem to be all the requests that Firebase does.

I have successfully integrated Firebase Performance Monitor as I can see custom traces and other info ( app_launch and so on) .

Do I need to do any extra setup? Why doesn't my http request appear in the tab? It would be nice to at least see that it tracked it, something like "login.page.com/**"

Comment: What are you using to make your network requests?

Comment: Are you using NSURLConnection for your networking requests? Firebase Performance iOS currently only supports NSURLSession networking requests. Support for NSURLConnection will be coming soon.

Comment: I am using NSURLConnection for most of my calls, but for test purposes I replaced some calls to NSURLSession and still nothing appeared. I tested it locally, so that means 2-3 requests were made with NSURLSession. Is the number too low? How can I test to be sure I will have some information appear in the console?

Comment: I replaced NSURLConnection with NSURLSession and I started to see the domains appear in the performance monitor. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear! Yes, there are a minimum number of events required per url pattern before they can appear in the performance monitor console.